# Django - how can i insert '.json' file to SQLite DB?

Tags: python, json, django, sqlite

my '.json file' like

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "firstName": "AAAAA",
      "lastName": "as23",
      "phoneNumber": "123456",
      "emailAddress": "AAAAA@test.com",
      "homepage": "https://amogg.tistory.com/1"
    },
    {
      "userId": 2,
      "firstName": "BBBB",
      "lastName": "h5jdd",
      "phoneNumber": "123456",
      "homepage": "https://amogg.tistory.com/2"
    },
    {
      "userId": 3,
...
```

i was search that to google, and try to this problem.. but unresolved.
so i use pandas and sqlite3

```py
import sqlite3 as db
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('test.json')
con = db.connect('./test.db')

df.to_sql('test', con=con)
```

so DB is created, but .json file data dont save in DB
how can solve this problem...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create the table 'test' beforehand, iterate over the pandas dataframe df and insert the records into the table one by one:

```
import sqlite3 as db
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('test.json', orient='index')
con = db.connect('./test.db')
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute('''create table test (userId int primary key,
                                     firstName text,
                                     lastName text,
                                     phoneNumber text,
                                     emailAddress text,
                                     homePage text)''')


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for element in row.iteritems():
        try:
            firstName = element[1]['firstName']
        except:
            firstName = ''
        try:
            lastName = element[1]['lastName']
        except:
            lastName = ''
        try:
            phoneNumber = element[1]['phoneNumber']
        except:
            phoneNumber = ''
        try:
            emailAddress = element[1]['emailAddress']
        except:
            emailAddress = ''
        try:
            homepage = element[1]['homepage']
        except:
            homepage = ''

        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)", (element[1]['userId'],
                                                                 firstName,
                                                                 lastName,
                                                                 phoneNumber,
                                                                 emailAddress,
                                                                 homepage))

con.commit()
con.close()
```

Since not all the records have the same valid values for all the columns, you will need to validate the existance of the column with a try/except and store an empty string if the column does not exist in the row.